# Java: Passing generic type to an another generic type class

Tags: java, generics

Main.Java : Main Class which creating the object of Test which of generic type 
Test.Java: Its Generic class which is creating object of Wrapper class of generic type
Wrapper.java: Its a Generic Class of Type 
We are passing String,Long as type for creating Test.java object . And passing long as a type for creating the object of Wrapper class.
Main.Java:

```
    public class MainClass {
   Test<String,Long> test;

   MainClass()
   {
       test = new Test<String,Long>(){};   
   }
   public static void main(String[] arr)
   {
       MainClass m = new MainClass();
   }
  }
```

**Test.Java**

```
     public class Test<T,U> 
    {
     Wrapper<U> mywrapper;
    Test()
    {
      Type type = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      System.out.println("TYPE: " + type.toString());

      Type type1 = ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      System.out.println("TYPE1: " + type1.getClass().getName());


      Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType)type).getActualTypeArguments();

      for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("TYPES[" + i + "]: " + types[i].toString());
      }
      mywrapper = new Wrapper<U>(){};
  }
}
```

**Wrapper.Java**

```
 public class Wrapper<U> {
  Wrapper()
  {
      Type type = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      System.out.println("TYPE: " + type.toString());

      Type type1 = ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      System.out.println("TYPE1: " + type1.getClass().getName());


      Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType)type).getActualTypeArguments();

      for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("TYPES[" + i + "]: " + types[i].toString());
      }
  }
}
```

And after executing the program we are getting output as
        TYPE: Test
        TYPE1: java.lang.Class
        TYPES[0]: class java.lang.String
        TYPES[1]: class java.lang.Long
        **TYPE: Wrapper
        **TYPE1: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl
        TYPES[0]: U****

So from the output you can see for the Wrapper class we are getting Type as U instead of Long as you can see in Test.Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the following program will clarify your doubt.

```
public class VMGeneric<A>
{
    private A objVariable;

    public VMGeneric(A localVariable)
    {
        objVariable = localVariable;
    }

    public String getNameOfGenericType()
    {
        return objVariable.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VMGeneric<String> o1 = new VMGeneric<>("");
        VMGeneric<Object> o2 = new VMGeneric<>(new Object());

        System.out.println(o1.getNameOfGenericType());
        System.out.println(o2.getNameOfGenericType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So from the output you can see for the Wrapper class we are getting
>   Type as U instead of Long as you can see in Test.Java.

Right. Class metadata reflects what is written at compile time. So in order to get the type it must be hard-coded at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get the type of the Parameter in Wrapper.java .  Actually my doubt is why its working in first level indirection and not working for Wrapper.java. On problem I found in my code is that mywrapper = new Wrapper(){}; will create an anonymous class of type U and thats the reason its printing U as datatype. But if I remove the {} then I am getting classclassException as Wrapper.java

```
 java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: In Wrapper, U is not a parameter. Instead You are saying Your class can accept any type of object instead of U. No one will know until you pass the real object. Again U is not a parameter.